# System does not sleep after restoring the default settings using SetThreadExecutionState

Tags: winapi, c#-4.0, timer, pinvoke

I created a method to prevent the system from sleeping as follows:

```
    public static void KeepSystemAwake(bool bEnable)
    {
        if (bEnable)
        {
            EXECUTION_STATE state = SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS);
        }
        else
        {
            EXECUTION_STATE state = SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS);
        }
    }
```

The method prevents the system from sleep but when I call the ES_CONTINUOUS part of the method,the system does not sleep at all when I want it behave normally. What am I missing? I'm running this code in a different thread (Timer)

Comment: *the system does not sleep at all when I want it behave normally* Presumably you have proved that no other process has called `SetThreadExecutionState` to keep the PC awake, right?

Comment: Yup. Its just my application. When I stop my application everything is back to normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm running this code in a different thread (Timer)

If you're using something like a `System.Threading.Timer` callback, it will be called on different (read: arbitrary) threads.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The callback method executed by the timer should be reentrant, because it is called on ThreadPool threads

Make sure you're calling `SetThreadExecutionState` for the same thread. Ideally, you'll serialise calls onto one thread (like the main thread).

Comment: I'll try running the SetThreadExecutionState on the UI thread of my app and let you know :)

Comment: you were right. I made sure the SetThreadExecutionState happens only on one thread and now it works perfectly. Thanks